# My changes in javascript file not reflecting in my plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I made change in Javascript file. Tried disabling plugin/re-activating/deleting javascript file and reuploading but nothing seems to upload the page as per my new javascript code.

Finally I went into view source and noticed the script src is set to `"wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/js/my-plugin.js?ver=4.3.1"`

If I type in this URL in the browser I get my old code back. However if I remove the query string at the end `?ver=4.3.1` it loads my new file code.

I am not sure who added `ver=4.3.1`. I don't have it in my plugin code. Could anybody please let me know how do I remove this and request my latest javascript code? It's been now more than a hour I am unable to fix this issue.

Many thanks!

Comment: Most likely WP add it. If you check the style links and other plugins you will notice that they have the same type of info appended. You might have to tell WP to clear the cache.

Comment: @jeff: How do I tell WP to clear the cache?

Comment: I haven't used WP for a long time but you should find something in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that wp_enqueue_script function is used in your plugin, to load this javascript file.

> **wp_enqueue_script** (*string $handle, string $src = false, $deps = array(), **$ver = false**, $in_footer = false*)

Based on [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), it tooks **$ver** as optional argument:

> (string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying script version number,
>   if it has one, which is **added to the URL as a query string for cache
>   busting purposes. I**f version is set to false, a version number is
>   automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. If
>   set to null, no version is added.
>
> Default value: false

String "ver=4.3.1" is added automatically, because you didn't specify $ver variable in function call. So the problem is in your browser, because it loads cached version.

As quick solution, if your plugin is not in production, you can just delete cache of your browser. But this solutions doesn't help other users, who didn't delete cache.

If you change "ver=4.3.1" string in source code to something else, your browser will load new version of javascript file. You can do it with modification of your wp_enqueue_script call. Example:

```
wp_enqueue_script( "my_plugin_js_handle", "path_to_js_file", array(), "1.2.3" );
```

- Replace **my_plugin_js_handle** string with unique handle of your choice.
- Replace **path_to_js_file** with url to your js file
- Replace **1.2.3** with actual version number of your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is because WordPress cache your JavaScript file . To get rid of caching problem set version attribute that change everytime you run WordPress like . I usually use time function

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'handle', 'src', array() , time() );
```

Comment: In this case, script will be never cached and will be reloaded on every page load. It will fix issue from question, but it's not the right solution. Also, the 3th parameter should be array and not boolean.